# Scrollbar on flex item when bigger than dynamic width parent

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a centered flexbox structure which displays box with list of customers.

I would like to achieve that when screen becomes narrower than content inside `#box` div, it doesnt hide beyond viewport but adds overflow to longest item, which is `#list` with table, so `#box` can shrink dynamically.

> It works like it should, when i add `width: 100%` to `#box` but i dont want the
>   box full screen width until it is not at least at the size of the content.

[**| JSFIDDLE DEMO |**](https://jsfiddle.net/65wfnegs/1/)

```css
body, html {
  
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 font-size: 16px;
  
}

* {
  
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
}

#wrap {
  
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 40px;
  flex-direction: column;
  
}

#box {
  
  background-color: #dcdcdc;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /*width: 100%; this works, but dont want it full until box is equal or smaller than content*/
  
  
}

#box > div {
  
  flex: 1 0 auto!important;
  
}

#title {
  
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: blue;
}

table {
  
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
}

table thead {
  
  font-weight: bold;
}

table tbody tr {
  
  height: 30px;
}

table td {
  
  padding: 0 5px;
}

#list {
  
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
  
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="box">
      <div id="title">
      List of customers
      </div>
      <div id="list">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td>First name</td>
            <td>Last name</td>
            <td>Address</td>
            <td>Telephone</td>
            <td>Decription</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Smith</td>
            <td>25th Jeffersons</td>
            <td>555 2589654123</td>
            <td>Pretty bad boy</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Anna</td>
            <td>Redford</td>
            <td>Trading street 252</td>
            <td>555 2541258745</td>
            <td>Booty babe</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jack</td>
            <td>Jackson</td>
            <td>Dummy Dumm 55</td>
            <td>555 123456789</td>
            <td>Random persona</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Buck</td>
            <td>Buckson</td>
            <td>Dummy Dumm 66</td>
            <td>555 987654321</td>
            <td>Another random persona</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

1 - full screen window

2 - resized (smaller) window

3 - resized (smaller) window - desired result

1[image: 1-full]2[image: 2-small]

3[image: 3-small-desired]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding `max-width: 100%;` instead of `width: 100%;` for the `#box` - it should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body, html {
  
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 font-size: 16px;
  
}

* {
  
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
}

#wrap {
  
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 40px;
  flex-direction: column;
  
}

#box {
  
  background-color: #dcdcdc;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /*width: 100%; this works, but dont want it full until box is equal or smaller than content*/
max-width:100%;
  
  
}

#box > div {
  
  flex: 1 0 auto!important;
  
}

#title {
  
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: blue;
}

table {
  
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
 max-width: 100%;
}

table thead {
  
  font-weight: bold;
}

table tbody tr {
  
  height: 30px;
}

table td {
  
  padding: 0 5px;
}

#list {
  
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
  
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="box">
      <div id="title">
      List of customers
      </div>
      <div id="list">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td>First name</td>
            <td>Last name</td>
            <td>Address</td>
            <td>Telephone</td>
            <td>Decription</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Smith</td>
            <td>25th Jeffersons</td>
            <td>555 2589654123</td>
            <td>Pretty bad boy</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Anna</td>
            <td>Redford</td>
            <td>Trading street 252</td>
            <td>555 2541258745</td>
            <td>Booty babe</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jack</td>
            <td>Jackson</td>
            <td>Dummy Dumm 55</td>
            <td>555 123456789</td>
            <td>Random persona</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Buck</td>
            <td>Buckson</td>
            <td>Dummy Dumm 66</td>
            <td>555 987654321</td>
            <td>Another random persona</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/65wfnegs/4/ i have also updated your fiddle you should use max-width for box and table instead of giving width :)